# How to access root viewmodel in aurelia inside compose

Tags: aurelia

I'm using aurelia compose inside my application like this:

```
<compose view-model="childViewModel" model="{myActivationParameters: ...}"></compose>
```

How can I access the parent view model inside the `childViewModel` html code?

In the end I want to be able to do this inside the `childViewModel.html`

```
<span> ${ ParentViewModel.myProperty } and ${ RootViewModel.myOtherProperty } </span>
```

I'm looking for knockoutJs `$root` and `$parent` equivalent in aurelia.

---

**edit:** I'm using aurelia composition instead of custom components. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aurelia Custom Elements: Access Parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390793/aurelia-custom-elements-access-parent-method)

Comment: Have you tried $parent? `<span> ${ $parent.myProperty } and ${ RootViewModel.myOtherProperty } </span>`

Comment: @JessedeBruijne Not a duplicate. He uses a compose element, and not a custom element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a compose element, you have access to the context of his parent. So, just do `${myProperty}`. If you have properties with the same name in the 2 viewmodels, you can't access the parent property.

In a future release, you will need to add the attribute `inherit-binding-context` in your compose element (See https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/issues/222)